# Component stops functioning when I reload the page. What could be the cause?

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion

Im creating a candlechart project in React using Syncfusion components. I have been trying to find the solution to a problem where the data isnt displayed in the chart when I load the page. If I make a change to the file that contains the component it does function properly. Using the react browser extension I can see that the state does in fact have the data, so I assume it might have something to do with the rendering. Any help / tips would be very welcome.

ps: I am pretty sure it does not have anything to do with the syncfusion components, since the data also doesnt load in as a mapped div after reloading.

Chart component:

```
export default class CandleChart extends React.Component {
 
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        candleChartData: props.chartData 
      }
    }
    
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="control-pane">
          <div className="control-section"> 
            <StockChartComponent
                id="stockchartdefault"
                primaryXAxis={{
                valueType: 'DateTime',
                majorGridLines: { width: 0 },
                majorTickLines: { color: 'transparent' },
                crosshairTooltip: { enable: true },
                }}
                primaryYAxis={{
                labelFormat: 'n0',
                lineStyle: { width: 0 },
                rangePadding: 'None',
                majorTickLines: { height: 0 },
                }}
                chartArea={{ border: { width: 0 } }}
                tooltip={{ enable: true, shared: true }}
                tooltipRender={tooltipRender}
                crosshair={{ enable: true }}
                load={load.bind(this)}
                title="AAPL Stock Price"
            >
                <Inject
                services={[
                    DateTime,
                    Tooltip,
                    RangeTooltip,
                    Crosshair,
                    LineSeries,
                    SplineSeries,
                    CandleSeries,
                    HiloOpenCloseSeries,
                    HiloSeries,
                    RangeAreaSeries,
                    Trendlines,
                    EmaIndicator,
                    RsiIndicator,
                    BollingerBands,
                    TmaIndicator,
                    MomentumIndicator,
                    SmaIndicator,
                    AtrIndicator,
                    Export,
                    AccumulationDistributionIndicator,
                    MacdIndicator,
                    StochasticIndicator,
                ]}
                />
                <StockChartSeriesCollectionDirective>
                <StockChartSeriesDirective
                    dataSource={this.state.candleChartData}
                    xName="x"
                    type="Candle"
                    animation={{ enable: true }}
                />
                </StockChartSeriesCollectionDirective>
            </StockChartComponent>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```